# Update priority of existing item in a minmax heap

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, heaps

Say you have a double ended priority queue in the form of a minmax heap as described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-max_heap).

What is the most efficient algorithm to update the priority of an existing item?

Assume that

1. I explicitly want to avoid deleting and re-inserting the item
2. The index of the existing item (pre-update) in the heap is known (so no linear search needed to find it)

---

My general thoughts so far: Let i be the index of the item to be updated.

First, update its actual priority value `priority[i] = new priority`, then ...

1. `i=0` (root of the smallest min layer), or `i=1` or `i=2` (roots of the largest max layer), then update the value and sift down
2. If `i` is at a leaf position, then sift-up as usual

The interesting cases happen if neither of this is true of course, i.e. i is somewhere in the middle of the tree. And that's where I'm not quite sure about correctness.

I think the following should hold true:

3. If `i` is on a min layer, and the `priority[i] < priority[grandparent_of[i]]`, then `SiftUp(i)`
4. If `i` is on a max layer, and `priority[i] > priority[grandparent_of[i]]`, then `SiftUp(i)`

Even trickier..

5. If `i` is on a min layer, and `priority[i] > priority[parent_of[i]]`, then...

   - Swap priorities: `(priority[i], priority[parent_of[i]] )= (priority[parent_of[i], priority[i])`. Afterwards,
   - `SiftUp(parent_of[i])`, then
   - `SiftDown(i)`
6. Similarly, if `i` is on a max layer, and `priority[i] < priority[parent_of[i]]`, then...

   - Swap priorities: `(priority[i], priority[parent_of[i]] )= (priority[parent_of[i], priority[i])`. Afterwards,
   - `SiftUp(parent_of[i])`, then
   - `SiftDown(i)`
7. And if neither of these conditions are fulfilled, then.. I think the heap is still valid and nothing needs to be done, unless I missed a case!

I'm having a very hard time arguing about the correctness of anything after step 2 though, so I wonder if this is actually right.

My thinking behind the logic of step 5, for example, is:

- Since `i`is on a min-layer, and hence `parent[i]` is on a max-layer, the entire subtree of `parent[i]` must have values smaller than `priority[parent[i]]`. Since we're swapping `priorioty[parent[i]]` with some larger value, that invariant is definitely still satisfied.
- The entire subtree of `i` must have values smaller than `priority[i]`.   We know that the value being swapped into slot `i` is larger than the value that was there before. Hence, this invariant is still satisfied too.
- Since we have replaced `priority[parent[i]]` with something larger, it's possible that after the swap, `priority[parent[i]] > priority[grandparent_of[parent[i]]]`, hence we sift-up `parent[i]`
- Similarly, since we have replaced `priority[i]` with something larger, it's possible that `priority[i] > priority[grandchild_of[i]]`, so we sift-down `i`

Is there any literature on how an update really looks like? Or does anyone smarter than me have any thoughts on correctness of my idea above?